# Where to find Lucene.Net EdgeNGramTokenFilter

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

From an article on the web, I know there is a EdgeNGramTokenFilter for Lucene.Net, with namespace Lucene.Net.Analysis.NGram. However, I can't find its source and I can't find a dll (yes, I checked Nuget).

Where can I find the EdgeNGramTokenFilter for Lucene.Net?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find it in "Lucene.Net.Analysis.NGram" namespace, in Contrib.Analyzers project.

Answer (score 1):

Installing the [Lucene.Net.Contrib](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net.Contrib/) package from NuGet will add a reference to `Lucene.Net.Contrib.Analyzers` to your project.

You can then reference and add `using` statements referencing the `Lucene.Net.Analysis.NGram` namespace, but still won't have access to the source code.

Source code for the `EdgeNGramTokenFilter` can be found in the [official documentation](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/de/dfc/_edge_n_gram_tokenizer_8cs_source.html).